# How to scrub sensitive query strings from Heroku's router logs?

Tags: security, heroku, logging

Heroku's router writes query strings, including any secrets they may contain, to the log.

Here's an example, where it has written `secret_token=TOP_SECRET` to the log:

```
06 Aug 2020 01:10:10.100000 <158>1 2020-08-06T00:10:10.000009+00:00
  heroku router - - at=info method=GET
  path="/api/my_resource?secret_token=TOP_SECRET"
```

How can Heroku router log messages be scrubbed so they do not log sensitive data like this?

Comment: I don't think this can be configured, but for the specific example: are these tokens really sensitive after they are used?

Comment: @Chris substitute for api_token or something else sensitive that isn't single use. Another consideration is although reset_password_tokens tend to be single use, if this response errors before the token use is recorded, and the user doesn't retry their request, then the token is still usable.

Comment: Under what circumstances does the token get revoked? I assume single use (as above) but also a time limit. I am intrigued, why this log represents a significant security concern for your system? Baring in mind that not only Heroku, but other systems between client and server can log the URI.

Comment: Try not to focus on this this token being single use, that is not the point of the question, I wish I'd used a different example. Just assume the query string contains a secret that we want protected in case the log files are ever exposed. For your other question, if its over SSL/TLS, then only the server and client will have access to the URI path and querystring.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to "scrub" Heroku's logs. Those logs [don't last very long](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-history-limits), though based on  your comments I suspect that waiting for 1,500 other log messages to push the offending content off the end won't fit your needs. There _are_ [log drains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains) which let you "take full control of how your application logs are processed", though as far as I know apps with drains configured still generate basic Heroku logs. If I can confirm or disprove I'll add an answer.

Comment: (Also, TIL: "if its over SSL/TLS, then only the server and client will have access to the URI path and querystring". I always assumed that this stuff would get logged even over HTTPS. Nice to know that I was wrong.)

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Thanks, it's a good point the logs don't last long on Heroku. This is for when the logs are drained to Heroku logging add-ons like Papertrail, LogEntries, LogDNA. It'd be useful if the router log messages could be scrubbed/masked before they drain to the 3rd party.